# Suggest any links or documentation to integrate CCAvenue payment gateway in Nativescript

Tags: typescript, nativescript, ccavenue

I am trying to integrate CCavenue payment gateway in my nativescript app. I have tried by referring Android documentation but failed to code. Please give me suggestion.

Comment: Do you have links to the docs/sdks/APIs for that?

Comment: nope.. I dont have..

Comment: Without any documentation for an SDK or API it's impossible to do anything. Sorry

Comment: Is there an update on this? Have you been successful in integrating it into {N}?